# Understanding steps to deriving integral equation representing biexponential function without exponentials

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I'd like to implement a sum of exponentials regression program, and found what looks to be a reasonable algorithm from @JJacquelin in his article on using integral equations to carry out nonlinear regressions without having to resort to numerical optimization or monte carlo simulation.

https://www.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

In the article he takes the biexponential case:

$$
y = b\ \text{exp}(p\ x) + c\ \text{exp}(q\ x)
$$

and derives the integral equation:

[image: linear expression of biexponential function derived by @JJacquelin]

from which ordinary least squares regression can be used (on the first and second cummulative numerical integrations) to estimate $p$ and $q$, followed by another ordinary least squares regression on the original formula to determine the remaining coefficients.

I'd like to understand how he derived this equation. He says he took two successive integrations and then used the resulting formulas to do a substitution which eliminated the exponential terms from the final equation shown above. While I can compute the antiderivatives, I'm lost as to how to actually derive this equation. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y(x) = b\ e^{px}+c\ e^{qx}$$
$$\begin{cases}\int y\ dx=\frac{b}{p}e^{px}+\frac{c}{q}e^{qx}+c_1 \\
\int\int y\ dx\ dx=\frac{b}{p^2}e^{px}+\frac{c}{q^2}e^{qx}+c_1x+c_2\end{cases}$$
Solve this linear system for the two unknowns $e^{px}$ and $e^{qx}$.

Then, put them into $y = b\ e^{px}+c\ e^{qx}$

You obtain : $y=-pq\int\int y\ dx\ dx+(p+q)\int y\ dx+Cx+D$

Going from indefinite integrals to definite integrals with chosen lower bounds introduces some constants which are then included in $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Is your full name *Speedy J. Jacquelin* ?

Comment: Ha-ha ! Not always so speedy...

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why $x$ in the system of equations ($c_1 x$) is not an 'unknown'?

Comment: $x$ is a set of experimental values as well as $y$.. The unknowns are $p$ , $q$ , $C$ and $D$.

Comment: but in the second integration equation the left hand side is a scalar value, so mustn't $x$ be also a scalar? Thanks for your patience. I guess then I move the $c_1 x$ and $c_2$ parts to the left hand side, and then invert the matrix. It feels alien to me to do that with $x$.

Comment: Each above equation is not an unique equation, but a symbolic and simplified writing for as many equations as they are experimental points $(x_k,y_k)$ from $k=1$ to $k=n$. In fact $y = b\ e^{px}+c\ e^{qx}$ means $y_k \simeq b\ e^{px_k}+c\ e^{qx_k}$. To be more rigorous  $y_k = b\ e^{px_k}+c\ e^{qx_k}+\epsilon_k$ with $\epsilon_k$ denoting the scatter. The same for each integral, for example $\int ydx$ is not a unique value, but takes $n$ values. All this appears as preamble in the referenced paper.