# When $y(t) = \lambda x(t) - \int_{-1}^{1} (ts^2 + t^2 s^3 + t^3 s) x(s) ds$ has a solution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, integral-equations

The question is as follows:

Estabilish conditions for the integral equation
$$y(t) = \lambda x(t) - \int_{-1}^{1} (ts^2 + t^2 s^3 + t^3 s) x(s) ds$$
to have a solution.

$\textbf{Definitions and efforts:}$

Actually I do not know what to do! It's my first of this kind and I am trying to learn!

I just know that it is an integral equation which is said is Fredholm equation because the integration limits $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Can someone please let me know how can we attack to this problem and what are techniques?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens around $0$ to $t^{3} s x(s)$ if $x(s) = s^{n}$ for $n \le -2$?

Comment: @Mattos Thanks! I think is not defined. Because for example if $n \leq -2$ then $n+1 \leq -1$ and then we can write $s^{n+1} = \frac{1}{s^{-n-1}}$ for $-n-1 \geq -1$. So for example for $-n-1 = 1$ the integral is not defined. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, by the [p-test](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/testconv/testconv.html) the integral isn't defined if $x(s) = s^{n}$ with $n \le -2$. However, I'm not entirely sure why you write everything from "$s^{n+1} = \dots$" onwards, nor do I think it is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y(t) = \lambda x(t) - t\int_{-1}^{1} s^2 x(s) ds
- t^2\int_{-1}^{1} s^3 x(s) ds - t^3\int_{-1}^{1} s x(s) ds$$
$\int_{-1}^{1} s^2 x(s) ds=c_1 \quad;\quad \int_{-1}^{1} s^3 x(s) ds=c_2 \quad;\quad \int_{-1}^{1} s x(s) ds$
$$y(t) = \lambda x(t) - c_1t-c_2t^2-c_3t^3$$
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{\lambda}(y(t)+ c_1t+c_2t^2+c_3t^3)$$
$\int_{-1}^{1} s^2 x(s) ds=c_1= \int_{-1}^{1} s^2\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}(y(s)+ c_1s+c_2s^2+c_3s^3)\right) ds $

$c_1= \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-1}^{1} s^2y(s)ds+c_1\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-1}^{1}s^3ds +c_2\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-1}^{1}s^4ds +c_3\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-1}^{1}s^5ds = \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-1}^{1} s^2y(s)ds+\frac{2}{5\lambda}c_2$

$c_2= \int_{-1}^{1} s^3\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}(y(s)+ c_1s+c_2s^2+c_3s^3)\right) ds =\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-1}^{1} s^3y(s)ds+\frac{2}{5\lambda}c_1+\frac{2}{7\lambda}c_3$

$c_3= \int_{-1}^{1} s\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}(y(s)+ c_1s+c_2s^2+c_3s^3)\right) ds =\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{-1}^{1} sy(s)ds+\frac{2}{3\lambda}c_1+\frac{2}{5\lambda}c_3$

$\begin{cases}
\lambda c_1-\frac{2}{5}c_2= \int_{-1}^{1} s^2y(s)ds\\
\lambda c_2-\frac{2}{5}c_1-\frac{2}{7}c_3=\int_{-1}^{1} s^3y(s)ds\\
\lambda c_3-\frac{2}{3}c_1-\frac{2}{5}c_3=\int_{-1}^{1} sy(s)ds
\end{cases}$
$$\begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2 \\c_3\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
       \lambda & -\frac{2}{5} & 0           \\
       -\frac{2}{5} & \lambda           & -\frac{2}{7} \\
       -\frac{2}{3}           & 0 & \lambda-\frac{2}{5}
     \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}\int_{-1}^{1} s^2y(s)ds \\ 
\int_{-1}^{1} s^3y(s)ds \\
\int_{-1}^{1} sy(s)ds\end{bmatrix}$$

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(y(t)+c_1 t+c_2 t^2+c_3 t^3 \right)$$

Comment: Hi Jean ! This is waiting for you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561050/understanding-steps-to-deriving-integral-equation-representing-biexponential-fun . I prefer that **you** answer the question. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici : Hi Claude ! No sooner said than done.  Thank cordially.

Comment: @JJacquelin Many thanks! Sorry, so you mean this equation always has solution?

Comment: There is a solution in so far the three integrals be convergent. This depends on the form of the function $y(x)$. Of course, for some kind of functions $y(x)$ one of the integrals might be not convergent and as a consequence there is no solution in this case. Note also that the matrix which depend on $\lambda$ has to be invertible.

Comment: There is a typo in my above comment. Of course, I mean $y(s)$, not $y(x)$. Also, note that, if the integrals are convergent and in the particular case of non-invertible matrix, the three equations are not independent. In this case, at least one coefficient can be arbitrary, which means that they are an infinity of solutions instead of a unique solution.

Comment: @JJacquelin Many thanks for your knowledgeable answer!